# Having issues converting string to int using parseInt() function

Tags: javascript, string, loops, int, parseint

```
function largestNumber(n) {
  let output = "";
  var toInt = parseInt(output);
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    output = output + "9";
  }
  return output;
};
```

I dont know exactly how to get this to return an integer. I keep getting null, or no output. I have tried

```
 return output.toInt;

 var toInt = output.parseInt();
 var toInt = output.parseInt(output);
 var toInt = output.parseInt("output");
 var toInt = parseInt(output);
 var toInt = parseInt(output,10);
```

and a few other various ideas that I dont remember by this point xD.
the help is greatly appreciated!

*EDIT*

Thanks for the help guys I found the problem in my code was the

```
var toInt = parseInt(output);
```

needed to come after the loop and then call

```
return toInt;
```

However, Barmar (I hope I spelled your name right) has a much cleaner effective solution.

Comment: why you do `let output = "";` ?

Comment: How could `toInt` ever be anything other than `undefined` when it's based on parsing the integer from `output`, which you always initialize to `""`, just before the parse?

Comment: You are always parsing an empty string

Comment: You should use `Number(output)` if you want an empty string to be converted to `0`

Comment: It sounds like what you're looking for is `return parseInt(output);`.

Comment: thanks Barmar! I figured it out another way but your answer works great too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code always attempts to parse an integer from `output`, but you always initialize `output` to an empty string right before the parse, so you get no int as a result.

You need to wait until `output` has been built up to its final value before you use `parseInt()`.

```js
function largestNumber(n) {
  let output = "";
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    output = output + "9";
  }
  return parseInt(output);
}

console.log(largestNumber(5));
console.log(largestNumber(15));
```

But really, this can be done in a much simpler way based on what your logic is currently doing:

```js
function largestNumber(n) {
  return parseInt("9".repeat(n));
}

console.log(largestNumber(5));
console.log(largestNumber(15));
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript statements are executed in the order they're written in the function. So you need to call `parseInt()` after you do all the concatenations, not before.

```
function largestNumber(n) {
  let output = "";
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    output = output + "9";
  }
  var toInt = parseInt(output);
  return toInt;
};
```

Although there's not really a good reason to use a string in the first place, you can do this all with arithmetic:

```js
function largestNumber(n) {
  result = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    result = result * 10 + 9;
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(largestNumber(5));
```

Or even more simply:

```js
function largestNumber(n) {
  return Math.pow(10, n) - 1;
}

console.log(largestNumber(5));
console.log(largestNumber(15));
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, and taking the time! :)